# Parameter estimation distribution for hypergeometric distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Let the hypergeometric distribution is given by $h(k\mid N;M;n)$, where

- $k$ is the number of observed successes,
- $N$ is the population size,
- $M$ is the number of success states in the population and
- $n$ is the number of draws.

Now if I know $N$ and $n$ and have $k$ successes, I would like to estimate the number $M$. Of course, I could estimate it with $kN/n$. However, I would like to assign the probability distribution for all numbers between $k$ and $N-(n-k)$, that it is the number $M$.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maximum likelihood estimation:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Comment: Many thanks for your input. But if I have to assign a probability to each natural number, like saying the probability that $a$ is the value $M$ is $p(a)$, how would I do that? This is probably a very simple question, but I am insecure how to derive that from the maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: The standard answer is that you can't have probabilities here, instead you have to work with likelihoods.